# how to extract value from four dimensional netCDF data in R?

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, netcdf4

I have been searching for this quite a while, but still could not figure this out. Seems like the raster package is the one to extract, but only from two-dimensional data.

This example of four-dimensional data, a netCDF file contains hourly pressure level (4 levels) air temperatures for three consecutive days (72 hours).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIiX9-xHrtH2FT1torg53iPxyzLxSYQu/view?usp=sharing.

i just want to extact temperature at some point locations (xy), on its correspoding datetime and altitude (pressure level). Then add this as an additional column in this reference data:

```
ref_df <- structure(list(Latitude = c(40.68, 45.64, 50.31, 51.17, 
44.493564), Longitude = c(96.29, 97.107, 98.21, 
100.67, 105.01), timestamp = c("2019-05-01 15:52:14", 
"2019-05-01 18:52:29", "2019-05-02 21:52:30", "2019-05-03 00:52:29", 
"2019-05-03 03:52:15"), altitude_hPa = c(530, 570, 590, 600, 
610)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I tried below, following along this [Import 4 dimensional netCDF data into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182850/import-4-dimensional-netcdf-data-into-r): but does not seem to work.

```
library(ncdf4)
ncdata <- nc_open(ncfile)
temp <- ncvar_get(ncdata)
dim(temp) # this shows index of layers in each dimention, but how to link this?
```

I appreciate it if anyone could help. Bat

Answer (score 0):

The `raster` package is set up for 3-dimensional data (x, y and time) but you can loop over the 4th dimension. Here with `lapply`:

```
library(raster)
xy <- matrix(c(96.29, 97.11, 98.21, 100.67, 105.01, 40.68, 45.64, 50.31, 51.17, 44.49), ncol=2)
colnames(xy) <- c("lon", "lat")

v <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
      b <- brick("download.nc", level=i)
      s <-  extract(b, xy)
    })
```

`v` is a list with four elements (one for each pressure level). Each element has a matrix with the same number of rows as `xy` and the same number of columns as the number of dates in `download.nc`

Or get a single matrix like this:

```
v <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
      b <- brick("download.nc", level=i)
      s <- cbind(level=i, extract(b, xy))
    })  

vv <- do.call(rbind, v)

vv[1:8, 1:3]
#      level X2019.05.01.00.00.00 X2019.05.01.01.00.00
#[1,]     1             259.8976             259.9743
#[2,]     1             254.7902             255.7008
#[3,]     1             250.4961             250.6820
#[4,]     1             251.0643             250.8548
#[5,]     1             250.0989             250.1968
#[6,]     2             265.6487             265.6842
#[7,]     2             258.4251             259.0856
#[8,]     2             256.4043             256.4468
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert Hijmans! It brings me very close. But, how to extract temp only for corresponding datetime and altitude of each location?  rather than extracting for all altitude levels and datetimes for each location.